# Logging a particular row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In the method for

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

I have a grouped table view. If I wanted Row 1 of Section 1 to spit out an `NSLog`, how would I do that? Also, would it be different if I wanted Row 2 of Section 3 to make a log? So far, I've only been using this method to transition between nibs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dirt simple:

```
if(indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 1) {
  NSLog(@"Awesomeness");
} else if(indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 3) {
  NSLog(@"Something more awesome");
}
```